# From MySQL to SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please help me converting this into SQL server trigger.

Create a trigger that will cause an error when an update occurs that would result in a salary increase greater than ten percent of the current salary.

```
CREATE TRIGGER RAISE_LIMIT
     AFTER UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMPLOYEE
     REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O
     FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN (N.SALARY > 1.1 * O.SALARY)
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Salary increase>10%'
```

Comment: What is the primary key of the table, you will need to join `inserted` and `deleted` based on that

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, every trigger only runs **once per statement, not per row**, and the pseudo-tables `inserted` and `deleted` contain, respectively, the new and old versions of the rows. You must join these on the primary key to match up the versions.

Remember that these tables may contain **multiple or no rows**. The `UPDATE` function can tell you if a column was present in the `UPDATE` command, it will not tell you whether any rows changed.

The trigger runs within the same transaction as the `UPDATE`, and an error will cause an immediate rollback of all rows. **Do not** attempt to rollback yourself, this will cause spurious transactional errors. Instead use `THROW`.

[The docs are located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you should consult them for further syntax.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER RAISE_LIMIT ON EMPLOYEE
AFTER UPDATE
AS

IF (UPDATE(SALARY)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN deleted d ON d.ID = i.ID
    WHERE i.SALARY > 1.1 * d.SALARY))
BEGIN
    THROW 75000, N'Salary increase > 10%', 0;
END;

GO
```